# React leaflet make one marker ignore it's events, so other can be clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have code like this:

```
return <React.Fragment key={i + 100}>
                            <MapMarker
                              obj={object}
                              key={i}
                              position={positionMap[i]}
                              icon={objIcon}
                              objName={convDataArr[1]}
                              objType={convDataArr[2]}
                              objStatus={convDataArr[3]}
                              objcoalition={convDataArr[4]}
                              objUnderAttack={convDataArr[5]}
                              objNumUnits={convDataArr[6]}
                              pane={convDataArr[2]}
                              zIndexOffset={100}
                            //riseOnHover={true}
                            ></MapMarker>
                            <FlameMarker
                              key={i + 1000}
                              position={positionMap[i]}
                              icon={iconArray[21]}
                            >
                            </FlameMarker>
                          </React.Fragment>
```

which outputs 2 markers. FlameMarker is almost the same as normal marker. The problem is, when both markers are drawn, everything from visibility perspective works, objective marker is shown, and animating flame gif. But then, I cannot click my main marker, it's transparent, and clicks the map. I tried using

```
eventHandlers = {{
click: () => {}
},
}}
```

but then the gif is clickable, which is not what I want. When manually adding CSS in developer mode in Chrome, it works, but how can I add this style manually, considering react leaflet just removes every style given to it, and uses it's own?

Answer (score 0):

I did a little abuse, since I need the fix fast, will improve that later. I just placed a JS script

```
setTimeout(() => {
for(let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('img[src$=".gif"]').length; i++) {
document.querySelectorAll('img[src$=".gif"]')[i].style.pointerEvents = "none";
}
}, 1000)
```

and it executes on last line of componentDidMount.